# How to don't wait the function while it's working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have function

```
void Search(string text) { ... }
```

Inside there are many SQLite queries like

```
List<Word> words = Database.connection.Table<Word>().Where(x => x.word == text).ToListAsync().Result;
```

And it's needed some time to complete this (about 3 sec).
At this moment interface is freezed.

It's not good. How to solve this problem and don't wait this function?

Comment: Generally, you don't want to do that type of work on the UI thread. There are different ways to solve the problem but all of them will achieve their results by moving where that work is done so that it does not block the UI thread. A full answer to your question is probably asking a bit much so I'd recommend first checking out what recommendations/examples that are available on msdn.

Comment: Use either TPL (WP7) or `async`/`await` (WP8).

Comment: maybe `List<Word> words = await Task.Run(()=> Database.connection.Table<Word>().Where(x => x.word == text).ToList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk of your time is this bit of code

```
ToListAsync().Result
```

The LINQ statement itself does not do any work

```
xxx.Where(x => x.word == text)
```

until you request items from it. This can be either from a foreach statement, or a ToList statement. When you call `ToListAsync` you are requesting the work to be done asynchronously, which means that it will not tie up the UI thread. But then the `.Result` makes it synchronous. So, you are not taking advantage of the threading that is already provided. If you change the signature of the method and how you are getting the results, you'll be able to offload the work.

```
private async Task Search(string text)
{
    // execute the LINQ query with the TPL
    List<Word> words = await Database.connection.Table<Word>().Where(x => x.word == text).ToListAsync();

    // we are back on the UI thread
    foreach(Word word in words)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

There is no need to create a BackgroundWorker or make your code more complex. If you are developing for Windows Phone 7, you'll want to add the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) nuget package to your app.

Answer (score 0):

A `BackgroundWorker` is a good class for a novice at using threads. It has a simple interface and can even provide feedback to feed a `ProgressBar` in the UI as the work progresses. You can find full details with examples in the [How to use a background worker for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) page on MSDN. An example from the linked page:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method that gets run on the background thread. You can see that you even have the possibility to cancel the long running process at any time. The `ReportProgress` method is used to pass back a value representing the amount of work done.